The pre-image of a nice set is nice
When did people start to define some concepts followed the logic "the pre-image of a nice set is nice"?
For example, a function is continuous if the pre-image of all open sets are open; a function is measurable if the pre-image of all measurable sets are measurable...
And why is this logic so useful, like the collection of sets, many concepts are defined in the same way.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

That's just two examples, and they are actually natural. Continuous functions one is simply just from the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition and measurable function is simply what one needs to be able to do integration.

Will you have also concepts followed the logic "the image of a nice set is nice". For example, compactness and connectedness, to name a few.
